# Выходит ошибка Cannot read property '1' of undefined | NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
const commands = [];
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login("token"); 

 client.on('message', async (message) => {
    const command = commands.find(x => x[0].test(message.content));
    await command[1](message);
});

const cmd = {
    hear: (p, f) => {
        commands.push([p, f]);
    }
}


cmd.hear(/^(?:привет)$/i, async (message) => {
    message.reply(`Привет`)
});
```

При обработке команды "привет" выходит ошибка:Cannot read property '1' of undefined
Понимаю, что 1 - не найдено. 
А как исправить данную ошибку, понять не могу.

Comment: очевидно `find` вернул `undefined`, значит в массиве не найден элемент удовлетворяющий условию

Comment: Это понятно, как можно переписать данный код, чтобы было без массива?

Comment: в смысле "чтобы было без массива"?

Comment: Как заменить проверку команды в тексте пользователя, дабы не столкнуться с такой ошибкой вновь? 
Немного перефразировал свой вопрос

Comment: можно удалить код из обработчика и ошибки вообще не будет. Либо просто проверить, нашлось ли что-нибудь. Вообще, как я указал в предыдущем комментарии, проблема в том, что в `commands` нет команды, которую ты ищешь, а ты ее все равно вызвать пытаешься

Answer (score 0):

Бот реагирует на абсолютно ВСЕ сообщения, кем-либо отправленные. Следовательно, чтобы бот не реагировал на свои сообщения необходимо добавить незамысловатую проверку: `if (message.author.bot) return;`

Сама ошибка вылетает уже после отправки ответа бота, т.к. команда не найдена. Чтобы ошибка не вылезала, необходимо тоже сделать проверку: `if (!command) return;`

Исправленный код:

```js
const commands = [];
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login("token"); 

client.on('message', async (message) => {
    const command = commands.find(x => x[0].test(message.content));
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!command) return;
    await command[1](message);
});

const cmd = {
    hear: (p, f) => {
        commands.push([p, f]);
    }
}

cmd.hear(/^(?:привет)$/i, async (message) => {
    message.reply(`Привет`)
});
```